# How to get the active element in the color ramp node with Python?

Tags: python, shader-nodes

The color ramp node have the elements, but im unable to get the active element,

Exist any method or API in order to get the active element?

```
elements = my_color_ramp_node.color_ramp.elements
```

[image]

Comment: There seem to be no obvious way to get that information. Can you elaborate why you need that, maybe it's an XY-problem?

Comment: No problem XY, I need to get the active element, I'm creating a tool to better manage the color ramp with additional functions, but there seems to be no way to get the active element